# How to fill text vertically in javaFX?

Tags: javafx, label, hbox

[image]

I've tried stretch height and width out but only width can show text horizontally, not vertically.

Below is what I've tried.

```
    Label label5 = new Label("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    HBox hbox5 = new HBox();
    label5.setMinHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
    hbox5.getChildren().add(label5);
    hbox5.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    hbox5.setMinHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

but It seems doesn't work.

Please let me know if I missed something Thank you!

Comment: Use text wrapping

Comment: To give an example of what @MouseEvent said label5.setWrapText(true);

Answer (score 1):

you can `wrapText(true)` and `rotate(90.0)` your `Label` and worry less about the rest?

```
Label l = new Label("some long text goes here - ");
l.setWrapText(true);
l.setRotate(90.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is making sure you use a `Monospaced` `font`.

> Code Version:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication42 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Label label = new Label("Hello World");
        label.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced"));
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setMinWidth(1);
        label.setPrefWidth(1);
        label.setMaxWidth(1);


        root.getChildren().add(label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

> FXML Version:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="296.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="198.0" prefWidth="0.0" text="HELLO WORLD" wrapText="true" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

[image]

Comment: giving it a preferred size means it stretches to a certain point.. you can use `Double.MAX_VALUE`